# Match a specific expression across multiple lines with RegularExpressionValidator

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex

I'm trying to build a regular expression to match the text typed by a user in a multineline input

The text should be on that shape:

```
Class 1: Exemple1 
Class 2: Exemple2
....
```

Every line must respect that syntax.

I managed to create the regex for a single line but i can't find a proper solution to extend it to a multilines version

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator" runat="server"
 ErrorMessage="This is wrong!" ValidationExpression="^[Class]+\s[0-9]+:+\s+[a-zA-Z]+$"
ControlToValidate="txtUserInput"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator><br />
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: But this will only work for 2 lines right ? the number of lines is not known

Comment: You may use `\AClass\s[0-9]+:\s+[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\r?\nClass\s[0-9]+:\s+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\Z`. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/bleGnt/1

Comment: Thanks, i'm gonna give it a try. it seems to work in your demo but not in my project. Probably because the line break in VB.NET is a constant written VbLf or something like this... i'll have to adjust it. Anyway thank you!

Comment: Use `\r?\n` then. Or `[\r\n]+` (but this will match empty lines as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^Class[ \t]+[0-9]+:[ \t]+\w+(?:\r?\nClass[ \t]+[0-9]+:[ \t]+\w+)*$
```

Or, if the line breaks may be just CR:

```
^Class[ \t]+[0-9]+:[ \t]+\w+(?:(?:\r\n?|\n)Class[ \t]+[0-9]+:[ \t]+\w+)*$
```

Or, a more line break sequence agnostic version (where `\r?\n` is replaced with `[\r\n]+`, but it may match empty lines in between valid lines):

```
^Class[ \t]+[0-9]+:[ \t]+\w+(?:[\r\n]+Class[ \t]+[0-9]+:[ \t]+\w+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2WGmEl/1)

I suggest using `[ \t]` instead of `\s` to match horizontal whitespace (it will work both on server- and client-side) and replace `[a-zA-Z]` with `\w` that matches letters, digits and underscores, not just letters (since your example contains digits, too).

The main difference is the `(?:\r?\nYOUR_SINGLE_LINE_PATTERN)*` part, that matches all subsequent lines in the desired format, if any.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `Class` - a char sequence
- `[ \t]+` - 1 or more tabs or spaces
- `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits
- `:` - a colon
- `[ \t]+` - 1 or more tabs or spaces
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `(?:\r?\nClass[ \t]+[0-9]+:[ \t]+\w+)*` - 0 or more repetitions of an optional CR (`vbCr`) followed with a required newline char (`vbLf`) (or, if `[\r\n]+` is used, just one or more CR or/and LF chars, or if `(?:\r\n?|\n)` is used, a CRLF, CR or LF line break) and the pattern of the first line
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. much appreciated. 
I had problems with the previous suggestion and yours works perfectly. I think it has something to do with the line break but you seem to suggest the same thing as the guy before (\r?\n).